# How would I prove that the regular expression rejects string?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Prove that the regular expression $\Sigma\Sigma(ab\cup ba)^∗a$ rejects the string $aabaabba$.

Would this be because the union of $ab$ and $ba$ would not accept the string $aabaabba$? I'm just confused on how to explain it.

Comment: I don't know what "ΣΣ" means. Please also use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type math.

Comment: Presumably $\Sigma$ stands for $a \cup b$.

Answer (score 2):

Any word accepted by this regular expression has to be either in length 3 or to end with $aba$ or $baa$.

Try to prove this fact, and use it to show that $aabaabba$ must be rejected.

Comment: I think it should be "end with $aba$ or $baa$".

Comment: Yes. I made a typo there :o